# ASM x86 How to get the pointer from an array properly? (16-bit TASM / DOS)

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, tasm, segment

Allright folks, let's hope this is an easy one: I need to access an array to achieve double-buffering (I use mode 13h) in 16-bit TASM. BUT: No matter if I use "OFFSET", "BYTE PTR [Array]", "BYTE PTR Array", or whatever I have tried already, the program reads/writes to the incorrect memory block, which is partly behind the actual start of the array.

Heres my (for now not really optimised and very messy) code:

```
.MODEL  MEDIUM
.STACK
.DATA
        XPos    DW      0
        YPos    DB      0
        Color   DB      0

        BoxX1   DW      0
        BoxY1   DB      0
        BoxX2   DW      0
        BoxY2   DB      0

        VPage   DB      64010   DUP(0)  ;TODO: Size *might* be incorrect.
        PageSeg DW      0
.CODE

SetVGA13 PROC
        MOV     AX,     0013h   ;Screen mode 13.
        INT     10h             ;Set screen mode to AX.
        MOV     AX,     0A000h  ;Screen segment.
        MOV     ES,     AX      ;You can't affect segment registers
        RET
ENDP

;-------DrawPixel---------------
; WORD XPos  = x
; WORD YPos  = y
; BYTE Color = colour
;-------------------------------
DrawPixel PROC
        XOR     AH,     AH
        MOV     AL,     [YPos]
        MOV     DX,     320
        MUL     DX
        ADD     AX,     [XPos]
        MOV     DI,     AX
        MOV     AL,     [Color]
        MOV     ES,     [PageSeg]  
        ;ADD     ES,     DI
        MOV     ES:[DI],AL
        ;MOV     ES:[DI],AL
        RET
ENDP

DrawBox PROC
        MOV CL, [BoxY1]
        YLoop:
        MOV     BL,     CL
        PUSH    CX
        MOV     CX,     [BoxX1]
        XLoop:
        MOV     [XPos], CX
        MOV     [YPos], BL
        MOV     [Color],CL
        CALL    DrawPixel
        INC     CX
        CMP     CX,     [BoxX2]
        JNZ     XLoop
        POP     CX
        INC     CL
        CMP     CL,     [BoxY2]
        JNZ     YLoop
        RET
ENDP

WaitFrame PROC
        PUSH    DX
        ; Port #03DA contains VGA status
        MOV     DX,     03DAh
        IN      AL,     DX
        WaitRetrace:
        ; Bit 3 will be on if we're in retrace
        TEST    AL,     08h
        JNZ     WaitRetrace
        EndRefresh:
        IN      AL,     DX
        TEST    AL,     08h
        JZ      EndRefresh
        POP     DX
        RET
ENDP

RestoreVideo PROC
        ; Return to text mode
        MOV     AX,     03h
        INT     10h
        RET
ENDP

ClearScreen PROC
        XOR     CX,     CX
        ;MOV     ES,     [PageSeg] 

        ClearLoop:
        MOV     DI,     CX  
        ;MOV     ES,     [PageSeg]
        MOV     BX,     OFFSET VPage
        ADD     BX,     CX
        MOV     AL,     [BX];VPage[DI];ES:[DI] 
        MOV     [Color],AL 

        MOV     AX,     0A000h
        MOV     ES,     AX
        MOV     AL,     [Color]
        MOV     ES:[DI],AL

        INC     CX
        CMP     CX,     64000
        JNZ     ClearLoop
        RET
ENDP

Main:
        ;INITIALISE
        MOV     BX,     OFFSET VPage
        MOV     [PageSeg],BX


        CALL    SetVGA13
        ;CALL    MakePalette       

        MOV     [BoxX1],33
        MOV     [BoxY1],33
        MOV     [BoxX2],99
        MOV     [BoxY2],99

        ;LOOP
        GameLoop:
        ;DRAW
        ;CALL    DrawBox
        CALL    ClearScreen
        ;CALL    WaitFrame

        ;INPUT
        MOV     DX,     60h
        IN      AL,     DX

        CMP     AL,     75
        JNZ     NotLeft
        SUB     [BoxX1],1
        SUB     [BoxX2],1
        NotLeft:

        IN      AL, DX
        CMP     AL, 77
        JNZ     NotRight
        ADD     [BoxX1],1
        ADD     [BoxX2],1
        NotRight:


        CMP     AL,     1
        JNZ     GameLoop



        ;END PROGRAM
        Error:

        ;CALL    ClearScreen
        CALL    RestoreVideo
        MOV     AH,     4Ch
        INT     21h
        END     Main
```

This code shows a rainbow coloured box that you can move around with the left and right arrow keys,

```
;INITIALISE
        MOV     BX,     OFFSET VPage
        MOV     [PageSeg],BX
```

That is my sad attempt to getbthe pointer to my buffer, but doesnt return the correct one

Sorry that my question was not done, i realised that when i got out of bed immediately for some reason.

Comment: I recommend stepping through the code with a debugger (in your case Turbo Debugger) to review what is going on.

Comment: You don't mention which memory address or array (or even which instruction) you think is a problem.

Comment: I've voted to close this It isn't a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . There is no description of what the program does, how it works, what is expected, and what happens. There are references to possible problem accessing `Array` but there is no such variable in the code, nor is there an indication of where the poster thinks the problem is (a particular instruction). Some of the code is commented out in the game loop which I don't think makes this a good example.

Comment: `ds` is not properly initialized.

Comment: I don't want to read a big block of code with no indication of where the problematic line is.  So IDK if this is the problem, but keep in mind that base + (scaled-)index addressing modes treat the index as signed.  Maybe try using `lea reg, [address you want]`.  That might cost an extra instruction byte compared to a `mov` with the right immediate constant, but solves the syntax mystery.

Comment: @FrankKotler As well, what I did notice besides _DS_ not being set (it defaults to the _PSP_) is that _ES_ gets set to the **offset** of `VPage` which is entirely wrong. The poster might wish to initialize _DS_, _ES_  and `PageSeg` with something like this instead `MOV     BX, @data`, then `MOV  DS, BX` then `MOV  [PageSeg],BX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not how I would code things, I'll offer up a couple of suggestions that may get you closer to resolving your problems.

When your executable loads the *DS* and *ES* registers originally point to the [DOS PSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) for your program. In your case you need to at least point *DS* to your DATA segment. The DATA segment that is filled in at run time by the DOS EXE loader can be referenced in your code by prefixing the segment name with an @ (AT) symbol. So you can replace this code:

```
;INITIALISE
MOV     BX,     OFFSET VPage
MOV     [PageSeg],BX
```

With this:

```
;INITIALISE
MOV BX, @DATA           ; Set up DS with our program's DATA segment
MOV DS, BX              
MOV     [PageSeg],BX    ; VPage is in DATA segment, move segment to PageSeg
```

In your `DrawPixel` code you'll need to add the *VPage* offset to *DI*. Replace this code:

```
XOR     AH,     AH
MOV     AL,     [YPos]
MOV     DX,     320
MUL     DX
ADD     AX,     [XPos]
MOV     DI,     AX
MOV     AL,     [Color]
MOV     ES,     [PageSeg]  
MOV     ES:[DI],AL
```

with:

```
XOR     AH,     AH
MOV     AL,     [YPos]
MOV     DX,     320
MUL     DX
ADD     AX,     [XPos]
MOV     DI,     AX
MOV     AL,     [Color]
MOV     ES,     [PageSeg]  
ADD     DI,     OFFSET VPage    ; We need to add VPage's offset 
                                ; from beginning of PageSeg
MOV     ES:[DI],AL
```

Video mode 13h is 320x200x256 colors. The amount of video ram that is needed would be 320*200*1 = 64000. This could be changed from:

```
VPage   DB      64010   DUP(0)  ;TODO: Size *might* be incorrect.
```

to:

```
VPage   DB      64000   DUP(0)
```

With these changes the program seems to display a rainbow box and moves left and right on the screen with the arrow keys.

There may be other bugs but I don't know what you were trying to achieve. This code could be simplified greatly. My changes were the minimal ones to work with the way you coded your program and make it somewhat functional.

Comment: Thanks, a lot of the code was messed up indeed through my various attempts to make the double buffer work. And yes i knew that 64000 was the correct size, but before that the size was 63999 bytes. Thanks once again for helping me out